# GetOpt library for C#

Tags: c#, getopt

I'm looking for a getopt library for c#. So far I found a few ([phpguru](http://www.phpguru.org/static/getopt.html), [XGetOptCS](http://69.10.233.10/KB/cs/XGetoptCS.aspx), [getoptfordotnet](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/geoptfordotnet.aspx)) but these look more like unfinished attempts that only support a part of C's getopt.
Is there a full getopt c# implementation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a .NET Implementation of getopt: http://www.codeplex.com/getopt

Comment: The link is archived and may not be available any longer.

Answer (score 31):

Miguel de Icaza [raves about Mono.Options](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Oct-14.html). You can use the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Options/), or just copy the [single C# source file](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Options/Mono.Options/Options.cs) into your project.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://sourceforge.net/p/xacc/code/HEAD/tree/xacc/Utils/GetArgs.cs) is something I wrote, it works rather nice, and has quite a lot of features for the tiny amount of code.  It is not getopts however, but it may suit your needs.

Feel free to ask some questions.

Answer (score 2):

For posterity:

[CommandParser is another one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CommandParserCSharp.aspx) with a BSD license

Answer (score 1):

It's not getopt, but you might try [NConsoler](http://nconsoler.csharpus.com/). It uses attributes to define arguments and actions.

Answer (score 1):

The Mono Project has (or rather had) one based on attributes, but last I checked it was marked as obsolete.  But since it's open source, you might be able to pull the code out and use it yourself.

Comment: The cmd line parser in Mono would be great in the BCL. I use it all the time and think it's great.

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine suggested [docopt.net](https://github.com/docopt/docopt.net),
a command-line argument parsing library based on the [docopt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docopt) library for Node.JS. It is very simple to use, yet advanced and parses arguments based on the help string you write.

Here's some sample code:

```
using System;
using DocoptNet;

namespace MyProgram
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Usage string
            string usage = @"This program does this thing.

Usage:
  program set <something>
  program do <something> [-o <optionalthing>]
  program do <something> [somethingelse]";

            try
            {
                var arguments = new Docopt().Apply(usage, args, version: "My program v0.1.0", exit: false);
                foreach(var argument in arguments)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", argument.Key, argument.Value);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //Parser errors are thrown as exceptions.
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can find documentation for it (including its help message format) at both the first link and [here](http://docopt.org/).

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

For the record, [NUnit](http://nunit.org) includes a simple one-file command-line parser in `src\ClientUtilities\util\CommandLineOptions.cs` (see example usage in `ConsoleRunner.cs` and `Runner.cs` located under `src\ConsoleRunner\nunit-console`).  The file itself does not include any licencing information, and a [link](http://codeblast.com/~gert/dotnet/sells.html) to its "upstream" seems to be dead, so its legal status is uncertain.

The parser supports named flag parameters (like `/verbose`), named parameters with values (like `/filename:bar.txt`) and unnamed parameters, that is, much in style of how [Windows Scripting Host interprets them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ss1ysb2a.aspx).  Options might be prefixed with `/`, `-` and `--`.