# How do I tell mono where to find a library?

Tags: c#, mono

I'm trying to use Gnu.Getopt with mono. Following other questions here, I have done:

```
% gacutil -i .../gnu.getopt.net-0.9.1/Gnu.Getopt/bin/Release/Gnu.Getopt.dll
```

which works:

```
% gacutil -l | grep Gnu.Getopt
Gnu.Getopt, Version=0.9.1.24287, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d014b4ccdc53511a
```

but mono can't find it:

```
% grep Gnu Program.cs
using Gnu.Getopt;
% mcs Program.cs
Program.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gnu' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
```

Giving an explicit path to the DLL works fine:

```
% mcs -r:.../gnu.getopt.net-0.9.1/Gnu.Getopt/bin/Release/Gnu.Getopt.dll Program.cs
%
```

What am I missing?

**Update**

I noticed that `/usr/lib/mono/4.5` has symbolic links to everything in `/usr/lib/mono/gac` (e.g. `System.Core.dll` -> `../gac/System.Core/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll`). I inserted a symbolic link to `Gnu.Getopt.dll`, but the symptoms persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting on the mono list and hunting a bit further, the answer appears to be "don't use Gnu.Getopt"; [use Ndesk.Options instead](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Oct-14.html) as per [GetOpt library for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172443/getopt-library-for-c-sharp).

Answer (score 1):

If you looking a common way to use command-line options parser with mono, there is a file `Options.cs` located in `/usr/lib/mono-source-libs` (change `/usr` to the prefix where your mono is installed). 
  To reference recent version of the file installed on the system you can use `-pkg:mono-options` command-line options in compiler (`-pkg` is the `mcs` compiler options, which allows to reference system packages). 
Or you can just copy the file to your project and use it like any other cs file.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [mcs documentation](http://www.mono-project.com/community/help/) the only assemblies that are referenced by default when compiling:

```
mscorlib.dll
System.dll
```

Microsoft's CSC compiler has similar behaviour where a set of assemblies are referenced by default but other assemblies need to be passed to the compiler, even those that are in the GAC.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Giving "-r:Gnu.Getopt" or "-r:Gnu.Getopt.dll" fails as well,though. Also, monodevelop doesn't find Gnu.Getopt in the list of references. It lists all of the other dll's in /usr/lib/mono/4.5.